# Yarn fails with TypeError: Cannot read property 'yarnPath' of null

Tags: javascript, macos, yarnpkg, canvas-lms

I am trying to get yarn installed on my mac, yarn installs but running yarn commands hangs with the following error.

> >yarn

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'yarnPath' of null
    at loadRcFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:56945:49)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:56916:14
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:101331:14
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at parseRcPaths (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:101329:78)
    at Object.findRc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:101343:10)
    at getRcConfigForCwd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:56915:74)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:92694:56
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:310:30)
```

I have tried uninstalling yarn and reinstalling with

```
npm uninstall -g yarn && npm install -g yarn
```

and  that didn't fix this issue.
thanks in advance for the help...
cheers!

Comment: Have you tried installing yarn using an [alternative method](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install)?

Comment: Tried `brew install yarn` and `curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash` but got the same error with `Yarn was installed, but doesn't seem to be working :(.` appended.

Comment: I believe you are missing a few steps. I posted an answer, lets see how helpful that is.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so from the documentation, its possible you are missing a few things; Below is a step by step process on installing Yarn on Linux (UBUNTU). Try it lets see if you missed anything;

run

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
```

On Ubuntu 16.04 or below and Debian Stable, you will also need to configure the NodeSource repository to get a new enough version of Node.js.

Then you can simply:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install yarn
```

Note: Ubuntu 17.04 comes with cmdtest installed by default. If you’re getting errors from installing yarn, you may want to run sudo apt remove cmdtest first.

If using nvm you can avoid the node installation by doing:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install --no-install-recommends yarn
```

Note: Due to the use of nodejs instead of node name in some distros, yarn might complain about node not being installed. A workaround for this is to add an alias in your .bashrc file, like so: alias node=nodejs. This will point yarn to whatever version of node you decide to use.

If Yarn is not found in your PATH, follow these steps to add it and allow it to be run from anywhere.

Note: your profile may be in your .profile, .bash_profile, .bashrc, .zshrc, etc.

Add this to your profile: `export PATH="$PATH:/opt/yarn-[version]/bin"` (the path may vary depending on where you extracted Yarn to)

In the terminal, log in and log out for the changes to take effect
To have access to Yarn’s executables globally, you will need to set up the PATH environment variable in your terminal. To do this, `add export PATH="$PATH:`yarn global bin`"` to your profile, or if you use Fish shell, simply run the command `set -U fish_user_paths (yarn global bin) $fish_user_paths`

Test that Yarn is installed by running:

```
yarn --version
```

This should hopefully do the trick. If not let me know so we see what other solutions there are.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error whenever I tried to run the `yarn` command and solved it by removing a line from a .yarnrc.yml file that was located in the folder in which I was running yarn.

```
yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs <-- removed this line
```

Once I did that yarn worked again.

Comment: For me, I have an older yarn 1.22.4 I have to work with, which puts the file at the same path with `.js` extension, as opposed to `.cjs`.